# Bluetooth LE on Raspbian disconnects devices after few seconds

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

i'm using Bleno (https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno) for a small BLE project.

I've started with no problems on Raspberry Pi2 but switching on Pi3 i found that:

- If i connect to my "BLE Pi3" i can interact with the device only for 2-3 seconds, then i get disconnected (working on Pi2)
- If i try to read/write characteristics i receive a permissions error and i can't do anything (working

Comment: The permission error indicates that you need to bond with the other device ( send a security request if you are a slave/peripheral).

Comment: The connection is not expected to be dropped, do you see an error code for that?

Comment: @bare_metal Ok but how can i do it? As i said, on Pi2 i haven't this issue. Should i look for a config file or do something on my nodeJs/Bleno code?

Edit: No error code, i can stay connected and send 'request' only for 2-3 seconds. Is there a way to see more detail/logs for bluetooth?

Comment: Use the btmon command to get the HCI log. There you should see error codes and why you are being disconnected.